# Como solucionar el error de código 1265 de MySQL, ya que al momento de insertar un dato entero en una columna no me lo permite y me da el error

Tags: mysql, sql-server, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

¡ ESTE es el codigo de la base de datos, la tabla y los valores a insertar!

```
CREATE DATABASE prob_profesor;

USE prob_profesor;

CREATE TABLE profesor (
doc_prof varchar(15)NOT NULL,
nom_prof varchar(30),
ape_prof varchar(30),
cate_prof int,
sal_prof int,
PRIMARY KEY (doc_prof));


INSERT INTO profesor (doc_prof,nom_prof,ape_prof,cate_prof,sal_prof) 
VALUES
('63.502.720','Martha','Rojas','2','690.000'),
('91.216.904','Carlos','Pérez','3','950.000'),
('13.826.789','Maritza','Angarita','1','550.000'),
('1.098.765.789','Alejandra','Torres','4','1.100.000');
```

¡EL DATO QUE ME DA EL ERROR ES ESTE '1.100.000'!

¡LA RESPUESTA DE MYSQL ANTE ESTE ERROR ES ESTE Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'sal_prof' at row 4!

LA RESPUESTA DE MYSQL ES ESTA:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes declarado sal_prof como int,estas intentando insertar decimales en el, te lo va a tratar de tomar como entero y al encontrar 2 puntos en 1.000.000 no sabe como tratarlo. Si te fijas si insertas el valor 550.000 te lo va a tomar como 550. hay que insertar el valor directo 1000000

Comment: listo, muchas graciasss